# Trabalhando com tags no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Em um sistema gostaria de categorizar alguns usuários com tags. No entanto existem grupos de tags (por exemplo, grupo de tag UF, Interesses). Estou tentando fazer uma query onde consigo responder algumas perguntas como:

Quero todos os usuários do estado de SP ou MG e que gostem de Futebol e Basquete.

Minha estrutura de tabela é a seguinte:

Tabela users: id, nome

Tabela tags: id, nome

Tabela user_tag: id, user_id, tag_id

Tentei com a seguinte query:

```
SELECT users.*, tags.nome AS nome_tag FROM users 
    INNER JOIN user_tag ON user_tag.user_id = users.id 
    INNER JOIN tags ON tags.id = user_tag.tag_id 
WHERE 
    (tags.nome = 'SP' OR tags.nome = 'MG') AND 
    (tags.nome = 'Futebol' AND tags.nome = 'Basquete')
```

Não tive sucesso com a query acima. No exemplo acima seriam usadas tags do grupo UF e do grupo Esporte mas poderia ter outros grupos.

Qual a melhor maneira para se trabalhar com essa abordagem?

Obrigado.

Comment: Não é o nome da tabela que está errado? na descrição da estrutura está "user_tag" e na query está "tag_user "

Comment: Não, eu que acabei digitando errado na query. Já arrumei na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
select * from users where 
    id in ( 
      select user_tag.user_id from tags JOIN user_tag ON user_tag.tag_id = tags.id
      where tags.nome IN ('MG', 'SP') 
    )

    AND id IN (        
      select user_tag.user_id from tags JOIN user_tag ut ON user_tag.tag_id = tags.id
      where tags.nome IN ('basquete', 'futebol') 
    );
```

nesse modelo você busca pelas tags que precisa e retorna os usuários relacionados, para mim é mais simples de entender, pois o usuário deve ser relacionado obrigatoriamente com os 2 grupos de tags.

Comment: Sua solução é funcional e mais simples que a minha, o importante é que funciona =D... como diz o ditado "a ordem dos tratores não alteram o viaduto"

Comment: simplicidade é a alma do negócio, menos manutenção é muito importante não podemos esquecer, funcionar só não é suficiente mais, digo por experiência com toda humildade é claro tenho muito que aprender, só quero deixar bem expressada minha opinião.

Comment: o AP sinalizou que estava a buscar todos os atributos da tab users + tags.nome **[..SELECT users.*, tags.nome AS nome_tag ..]** poderia ajustar sua resposta para ficar 100% ;)

Answer (score -1):

Em primeiro lugar creio que a forma que você está trabalhando não seja funcional pois logicamente não se usa uma referência como o estado do usuário em uma tag. Para melhor tratamento utilize uma nova coluna assim facilita tanto nas consultas quanto nas views.

Sua solução está abaixo **(testei no SQLServer, portanto a linguagem está como a dele)**:

```
--construindo o contexto
CREATE DATABASE teste
GO
USE teste
GO
CREATE TABLE users    ( [id] INT, [nome] VARCHAR(100) )
GO
CREATE TABLE tags     ( [id] INT, [nome] VARCHAR(100) )
GO
CREATE TABLE user_tag ( [user_id] INT, [tag_id] INT )
GO
--populando users
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'Joao');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2,'Pedro');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3,'Maria');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4,'Ana');
--populando tags
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1,'SP');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2,'MG');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3,'Basquete');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (4,'Futebol');
--populando user_tag
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (1,1); --> Joao  | SP
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (2,1); --> Pedro | SP
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (3,1); --> Maria | SP
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (4,2); --> Ana   | MG
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (1,3); --> Joao  | Basquete
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (1,4); --> Joao  | Futebol
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (2,1); --> Pedro | Basquete
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (3,2); --> Maria | Futebol
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (4,3); --> Ana   | Basquete
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (4,4); --> Ana   | Futebol
--solucao
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    users
WHERE
    --verifica se é ou de SP ou de MG
    (   SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
        FROM user_tag
        INNER JOIN tags ON (user_tag.tag_id = tags.id)
        WHERE 
            user_tag.user_id = users.id AND
            tags.nome IN ('SP','MG')
    )  = 1 AND
    --verifica se gosta de Basquete
    (   SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
        FROM user_tag
        INNER JOIN tags ON (user_tag.tag_id = tags.id)
        WHERE
            user_tag.user_id = users.id AND
            tags.nome = 'Basquete'
    ) = 1 AND
    --verifica se gosta de Futebol
    (   SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) 
        FROM user_tag 
        INNER JOIN tags ON (user_tag.tag_id = tags.id) 
        WHERE
            user_tag.user_id = users.id AND
            tags.nome = 'Futebol'
    )  = 1
```

Basicamente o que você deveria fazer é avaliar cada tag de consulta em uma subconsulta no `WHERE`. Ao usar o `TOP 1` na subconsulta você garante que o resultado será um único registro para a comparação na consulta original. Se você tivesse mais comparações a serem feitas, seria necessário apenas adicionar mais uma subconsulta.

Comment: AP postou código assim **SELECT users.*, tags.nome AS nome_tag FROM users** logo ele quer mais do que apenas o que esta na tab users seu código tendo apenas o ***SELECT * FROM users** esta incompleto, a resposta, mesmo eu tendo corrigido o erro de sintaxe continua errado.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Corrigindo para que não fique uma resposta inválida, segue novo select, agora ficou bem próximo do que já foi postado aqui, mas ainda assim é um select **"diferente"** apenas mais uma opção de se fazer a mesma coisa, deixei o select bem enxuto!.

Fazendo uso da informações de **entrada** do Sr. LeandroLUK, mas com uma solução diferente no **SELECT** segue abaixo:

```
SELECT distinct u.*,t1.nome,t2.nome FROM 
users u, tags t1, tags t2, user_tag r1, user_tag r2
WHERE
u.id = r1.user_id and
u.id = r2.user_id and
t1.id = r1.tag_id and 
t2.id = r2.tag_id and   
t1.nome in ('SP','MG') and (t2.nome in ('Futebol','Basquete'))
```

construindo o contexto

```
drop database if exists test;
CREATE DATABASE test;
USE test;

CREATE TABLE `test`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT '',
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '');

CREATE TABLE `test`.`tags` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT '',
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '');

CREATE TABLE `test`.`user_tag` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  COMMENT '',
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `tag_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  COMMENT '');

-- REFERENCIANDO DAS FOREIN KEY
ALTER TABLE `test`.`user_tag` 
ADD INDEX `fk_tag_idx` (`tag_id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
ADD INDEX `fk_user_idx` (`user_id` ASC)  COMMENT '';
ALTER TABLE `test`.`user_tag` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_tag`
  FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`tags` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user`
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`users` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;


-- populando users
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1,'Joao');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2,'Pedro');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3,'Maria');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4,'Ana');
-- populando tags
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1,'SP');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2,'MG');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3,'Basquete');
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (4,'Futebol');
-- populando user_tag
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (1,1); -- > Joao  | SP
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (2,1); -- > Pedro | SP
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (3,1); -- > Maria | SP
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (4,2); -- > Ana   | MG
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (1,3); -- > Joao  | Basquete
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (1,4); -- > Joao  | Futebol
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (2,1); -- > Pedro | Basquete
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (3,2); -- > Maria | Futebol
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (4,3); -- > Ana   | Basquete
INSERT INTO user_tag(user_id,tag_id) VALUES (4,4); -- > Ana   | Futebol
```

resultado

```
+----+------+------+----------+
| id | nome | nome | nome     |
+----+------+------+----------+
|  1 | Joao | SP   | Basquete |
|  1 | Joao | SP   | Futebol  |
|  4 | Ana  | MG   | Basquete |
|  4 | Ana  | MG   | Futebol  |
+----+------+------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```